# (vb.net) Convert Mail Attachment to Base64 String

Tags: vb.net, uipath-studio

Working in vb.net within UiPath Studio, I have a mail attachment object (System.Net.Mail.Attachment). I want to directly convert the attachment to a Base64 string. Is there a way to accomplish this, perhaps by utilizing the ContentStream method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to complete this using direct assignments. I'm working with an attachment object named Attachment. First, create the variables:

```
Stream as System.IO.Stream
Buffer as System.Byte[]
BufferLength as Int32
```

Then use an Assign activity for the following:

```
Stream = Attachment.ContentStream
Buffer = new Byte(Cint(Stream.Length)){}
BufferLength = Stream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)
File_Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Buffer)
```

The BufferLength assignment is a little hacky, but the Stream.Read method returns a value that is the length of the Read. That value isn't helpful for me, but to make this work in an Assign activity, I just accept the value in an integer variable.

Comment: This worked for me like a charm, but you have a couple of bugs: 1) Attachment.Name is not the correct property;  you need Attachment.ContentStream. 2) BufferLength assignment has an extra ) at the end.

Comment: Ah, what a terrible oversight! Thanks for catching and correcting it. I've updated my answer.